# waiting for .each to finish before continuing (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with the each function in jquery and it looks like it is moving on to a function that needs the results of the each loops before they are finished... here is the code

```
$.each(array, function(index, value) { 
  prob[value] = get_probs(value);
});

sim(prob);

function sim(prob){
  //alert ("test");
  alert (prob[value]);
  new_sim(prob[value]); 
}
```

if I uncomment the alert ("test"); piece it will obviously display an alert, then it will display the proper number in the second alert, however, if I leave it as is, it comes back undefined, which I can only assume is because it has gone on to the sim function without finishing the each loop

is there anyway I can get the sim function to wait to run until the each loop is finished?

note: there is more code than this, but I have tried to simplify... let me know if anything is unclear.  I am eventually going to run the sim function a bunch of times, which is why I want to set it up like this

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I assume `get_probs` or some other code is making an AJAX request, or doing some other asynchronous action.

Comment: that is right.  I just switched it to run synchronously (async:false) and it looks to be working... is there any other way to do this so I don't lock the browser for a second or two?

Comment: Whatever code relies on the AJAX response should be executed from the `success:` callback. One option is to *pass* a function as an argument to `get_probs` *(assuming that's where the AJAX is)*, then invoke that function inside the callback, passing it the response. Otherwise, instead of passing a funciton, you could just hardcode the code into the callback.

Answer (score 0):

The .each loop should run sequentially, nothing after it should execute until it's finished.

How about running this code:

```
sim(prob);

function sim(prob){
  //alert ("test");
  alert (prob[value]);
  new_sim(prob[value]); 
}
```

Inside the success callback of get_probs, sync ajax calls are never the answer.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that for all intents and purposes JavaScript is single threaded so you really don't have to worry about the processing going astray (Ajax calls aside)

Comment: Except in this case it looks like the `get_probs` function does an AJAX call, so the each loops through very quickly (starting up the AJAX calls) and will then run `sim()` before the AJAX calls return.

Comment: ya, as i commented above, there is an ajax call in get_probs, i set it to async:false and it works, but this is not ideal as it locks the browser for a second or two.  Is there another way?